# Setting multiple Prometheus alerts

Tags: prometheus, grafana, slack, alerts

I have an existing prometheus setup and it is configured in such a way that it is sending all alerts (critical and warnings) to one slack channel and is working fine with out any issues. Below is the image attached.

[Existing alertmanager.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAZ0a.png)

Now the question is, can we split the alerts based on the severity and then route them to different slack channels? Like, low severity alerts should be routed to one channel and high severity should go to a different channel?

I have modified alertmanager.yml file as below but it is not working and am not getting any alerts to any of the slack channels. Please advise.

[New_alertmanager.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6aQW.png)

Thanks,
Sharmila

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
route:
  receiver: 'channel1'
  routes:
    - match:
      group_by: ['alertname']
      group_wait: 10s
      group_interval: 10s
      repeat_interval: 24h
      continue: true
    - match:
           severity: Critical
      receiver: 'channel2'
      continue: true
    - match:
            severity: Warning
      receiver: 'channel3'

receivers:
- name: 'channel1'
  slack_configs:
        - send_resolved: true
          api_url: '$SlackWebhook1'

- name: 'channel2'
  slack_configs:
        - send_resolved: True
          url: '$SlackWebhook2'

- name: 'channel3'
  slack_configs:
        - send_resolved: True
          api_url: '$SlackWebhook3'
```

You can check on the code that all the alerts will go to channel1, the Critical ones on channel2 and the Warnings on channel3.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed my alertmanager.yml as per your suggestion. I will update if this has worked!!

Comment: I have modified my alertmanager.yml file but it isnt sending any alerts. I have attached the same to my question. Please check and advise. Thanks!

Comment: I need more info to check, edit your question.

Comment: @rcarba: where I can find the documentation related to this? I want to use other filters for the match case.

Comment: I think all the information I have is from Prometheus docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/notification_examples/